# phonegap-plugin-push do not register

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, push-notification

I'm learning on how to make app using phonegap and i'm trying to use phonegap push plugin from [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/) the issue is that after i initialize it the register event do not fire, i made this steps

- create the project with phonegap
- installed the plugin following the instructions using `phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"`
- the build the platform with `phonegap build android`

it added android platform and didt not show me any error. but when i run the app it doents fire the registration event. This is my  code

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "XXXXXXX"
        },
        "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, 
        "windows": {} 
    });
    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        alert("registration event");
        alert(data.registrationId)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        alert("notification event");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        push.finish(function () {
            console.log('finish successfully called');
        });
    });

    push.on('error', function(e) {
        alert("push error");
        alert(e);
    });
    alert('hello')

}
};
```

in the index.html the script are called this way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/push.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

its there something wrong? how do i know if the plugin its initializating? or why it isnt triggered the registration event.

Comment: GCM returns a payload. Parsing it will help

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var push = PushNotification.init({
       "android": {
           "senderID": "XXXXXXX"
       },
        "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, 
       "windows": {} 
   });
push.on('registration', function(data) {
    alert("registration event");
    alert(data.registrationId)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
    alert("notification event");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    push.finish(function () {
        console.log('finish successfully called');
    });
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
    alert("push error");
    alert(e);
});
alert('hello')
```

inside

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it didn't work. neither of the events (registration, notification and error) are being called